# C# Microsoft Acces Database Connection Error

Tags: c#, database, winforms, oledb, oledbconnection

My loggining form is stopping on `connection.Open();`, I'm getting an error: `System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: unrecognized database format`. Code with connection operations:

```
    OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();
    connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=W:\Data Base\Test.accdb;
Persist Security Info=False;";
    connection.Open();
    connection.Close();
```

What to do with that? Thank you very mutch for your help.

Comment: I'd say there's a problem with the `accdb` file format not being supported.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need the @ before your string.
Also I think you should do like this :

```
connection.ConnectionString = "Server=[server_name];Database=[database_name];Trusted_Connection=true";
```

Here is the source I used to answer you : https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/823854/How-to-connect-SQL-Database-to-your-Csharp-program

Comment: I'm using OleDb, not SQL server just MS Access